# Linha digitavel para codigo de barras VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, boleto

Eu estou tentando fazer com que a linha digitável seja transformada em código de barras e o plugin JsBarcode vá transformar em código de barras (visivel), mas acontece que preciso de uma formula para vuejs que transforma a linha digitável em codigo de barras.

```
    <template>
  <div>
    {{ linhaDigitavel }}
    <br />
    <div>
      <canvas id="barcode"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import JsBarcode from "jsbarcode";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      linhaDigitavel: "00190500954014481606906809350314337370000000100",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    gerarCodigoBarras() {
      // Verificar se a linha digitável não está vazia
      if (!this.linhaDigitavel) {
        console.error("Linha digitável não pode ser vazia.");
        return;
      }

      // Limpar o canvas antes de renderizar um novo código de barras
      const canvas = document.getElementById("barcode");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // Gerar código de barras
      JsBarcode(canvas, this.linhaDigitavel, {
        format: "CODE128",
        displayValue: false,
        fontSize: 14,
      });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.gerarCodigoBarras();
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

você pode criar uma função que analisa a linha digitável e a converte em um formato aceitável pelo JsBarcode

```
 <template>
  <div>
    {{ linhaDigitavel }}
    <br />
    <div>
      <canvas id="barcode"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import JsBarcode from "jsbarcode";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      linhaDigitavel: "00190500954014481606906809350314337370000000100",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    gerarCodigoBarras() {
      // Verificar se a linha digitável não está vazia
      if (!this.linhaDigitavel) {
        console.error("Linha digitável não pode ser vazia.");
        return;
      }

      // Limpar o canvas antes de renderizar um novo código de barras
      const canvas = document.getElementById("barcode");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // Converter a linha digitável em um formato aceitável pelo JsBarcode
      const codigoBarras = this.converterLinhaParaCodigoBarras(this.linhaDigitavel);

      // Gerar código de barras
      JsBarcode(canvas, codigoBarras, {
        format: "CODE128",
        displayValue: false,
        fontSize: 14,
      });
    },
    converterLinhaParaCodigoBarras(linhaDigitavel) {
      // Implemente a lógica de conversão aqui, de acordo com as regras do seu sistema
      // Este é apenas um exemplo básico
      return linhaDigitavel.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""); // Remove caracteres não numéricos
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.gerarCodigoBarras();
  },
};
</script>
```

Esta função converterLinhaParaCodigoBarras é um exemplo básico e pode não funcionar corretamente para todos os casos. Você precisará adaptar essa função de acordo com as regras específicas da linha digitável do seu sistema de boletos.